# fadeOut () hides all the header and I just want to hide the h1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide the h1 when the scroll is greater than 850, but when it goes below 850 also hides the nav. 
If I hide the nav without hiding the h1, then it doesn't return with the fadeIn ()
I don't understand why the nav is hidden, if I ask you to just hide the id '#marca'.

HTML and CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
    .header {
      position: fixed;
      margin-top: -23px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 70px;
    }

    .marca{
      display: block;
    }

    h1{
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    h1 a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }

    .vacio{
      height: 3000px;
    }

    /* MENU HEADER */

    .menu-negro,
    .menu-blanco{
      margin-top: -35px;
      /* display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end; */
      float: right;
    }

    .menu-negro a,
    .menu-blanco a,
    .menu-negro img,
    .menu-blanco img{
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .menu-blanco{
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/proba.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
        <h1 id="marca"><a href="Index.html">Marca</a></h1>
      <nav id="menu-negro" class="menu-negro">
        <a id="btn-carro" href="#"><img src="../logos/carro32pxnegro.png" alt=""></a>
        <a id="btn-usuario" href="#"><img src="../logos/usuario32pxnegro.png" alt=""></a>
      </nav>
      <nav id="menu-blanco" class="menu-blanco">
        <a id="btn-carro" href="#"><img src="../logos/carro32pxnegro.png" alt=""></a>
        <a id="btn-usuario" href="#"><img src="../logos/usuario32pxnegro.png" alt=""></a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="vacio">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  marca = $('#marca')
  menuNegro = $('#menu-negro')

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    window_y = $(window).scrollTop()
    scroll_critical = 850
    if(window_y > scroll_critical && marca.css('display') == "block"){
      marca.fadeOut()
    }
    if(window_y < scroll_critical && marca.css('display') == "none"){
      marca.fadeIn()
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that the fadeOut is hidding the entire nav, but this

when the `h1` marca is hidden, the `menu-negro` stop floating to him, and start floating to the parent element, so it just goes up because 2 things, the `header` has a `margin-top: -23px;` and the menus have a  `margin-top: -35px;`, what you could do is to add a class to change the margin of the nav like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  marca = $('#marca')
  menuNegro = $('#menu-negro')

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    window_y = $(window).scrollTop()
    scroll_critical = 850
    if(window_y > scroll_critical && marca.css('display') == "block"){
      $('.menu-negro').addClass('no-margin-top');
      marca.fadeOut()
    }
    if(window_y < scroll_critical && marca.css('display') == "none"){
    $('.menu-negro').removeClass('no-margin-top');
      marca.fadeIn()
    }
  })
})
```

and in the css just add

```
    .menu-negro.no-margin-top {
      margin-top: 23px;
    }
```